# Deploy React App with JSON data(json-server)

Tags: reactjs, json, deployment, fetch, json-server

Ok so I'm using JSON-server locally, I have an Events component that is fetching my events.json data file which is local. Everything is working fine and I'm displaying all the data as I need. Now I want to deploy it to Netlify or somewhere similar. My issue is that I don't know where to start - I've ran npm build and uploaded to Netlify and get: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I understand that JSON-server is a fake restful api. What would be the best approach to getting the app and JSON deployed?

```
export default function News() {
    const newsData = useLoaderData();

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = "Our-Ocean | News";
    });

    return(
        <div className="container news-wrap">
            <h1>All the latest happenings from our seas and beyond</h1>
            {newsData.map(story => ( 
                <div key={story.id}>
                    <div className={story.id === 1 ? 'story-first' : 'story'}>
                        <div className="image-and-meta">
                            <img src={story.img} alt={story.alt}/>
                            <div>
                                <p>Posted on: <b>{story.date}</b></p>                               <p>By: <b>{story.author}</b></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Link to={ story.id.toString() }><h2>{story.headline}</h2></Link>
                        <p className="story-summary">{story.body[0].substring(0, 250) + '...'}</p>
                        <Link className="sm-read-more" to={ story.id.toString() }>Read More</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

//loader function
export const newsLoader = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/news');
    return res.json();
}
```

Ive tried to npm run build and deploy as well as fetching file from folder not using json-server